# Write to a file in parallel using MPI or in serial?

Tags: mpi

I have a general question about MPI usage.

When you want to write data to files, for example, 100 files are gonna be created.

Do you prefer to use each rank (core) to write one file, or you prefer to write them serially, one by one? Which is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having each rank write to one file (serially), there will exist a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), so all writing must be done *atomically*. This will give much slower overall write time than having each rank write to its own file.

However you would then need some sort of reduce where the reduce joins two separate files.You would have to weight the communication / joining overhead against the wait time for writing serially (unless you will leave the files in parts).

Comment: So you mean, if I leave the files in parts, it would be quicker if I write in parallel?

Comment: Yeah definitely, if you don't care in which order the files are written. Essentially, all ranks waiting to write to one file would be the same speed as one process writing to one file, because you can't parallelize it.